# what does using the keyword 'this' in the following context imply

Tags: java

Why does the code throw null pointer Exception and what is the meaning of using 'this'. I am beginner, value any  help.

```
// class Foobar
private Foo f;
void get(){
    this.getFoo().handle();
}  
public Foolish getFoo(){
    return this.f;
}
void handle(){
    System.out.println("handle of the intrf");
}

// please note that

public interface Foolish {
    void handle();
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Foobar().get();
```

Comment: ??? Makes no sense... Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: please show a complete stack trace

Comment: Always make sure to check `if (this != null)` (joking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get an exception is that the member `f` of type `Foo` is not initialized to, say, `new Foo()` somewhere in the constructor or in the declaration.

The reference to `this` in this context means "the object itself"; it is entirely not necessary in your code, because there is nothing to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

Because `f` is `null` and `handle()` is called on it after being returned by `getFoo()`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like 'private Foo f' is ever initialized so this.getFoo returns null and 'null'.handle() would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are never initializing foo, you need something like the following,

```
foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: don't. it will cause infinite recursive constructor invokation

Answer (score 0):

It means it's returning the variable `f` of the current instance of your class `Foobar`. Here, it is redundant, since `f` is not ambiguous (there is no local `f` variable defined). Consider

```
class A {
  private int b = 1;

  public int m()
  {
     int b = 2;
     return b; // will return 2
  }
  public int n()
  {
     int b = 2;
     return this.b; // will return 1
  }
```